# Use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage() to Train the model

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning TensorFlow and trying to apply exponential moving average based gradient descent (instead vanilla gradient descent). Specifically I;m trying to use [tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) but the document doesn't seem to provide guide for how to use it to build model that drives optimization.

Full code is available at - https://github.com/vibhorj/tf/blob/master/so/ema.py
, but here's what i'm doing and the classifier isn't learning anything (after each epoch, w & b still remain same .. no learning)

**STEP1**: define weights & biases

```
with tf.variable_scope('scp1', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
w = tf.get_variable(name='weights', initializer = tf.ones(shape=[2,3],dtype=tf.float32))
b = tf.get_variable(name='bias', initializer = tf.ones(shape=[3],dtype=tf.float32))
```

**STEP2**: define error / loss / optimizer

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2], name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,3], name='Y')
Ylogits = tf.matmul(X,w) + b
error = -Y*tf.log(Ylogits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(error, name = 'loss') 
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)
```

**STEP3**: Created ExponentialMovingAverage object, created training_op that (I expect) to update the moving averages after each training step.

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.50,name='EMA')
training_op = ema.apply([w, b])
```

**STEP4**: Finaly run the iterations

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
    for epoch in range(10): #increase epocs later
        _ = sess.run([training_op], feed_dict=feed_train)
        print("\n POST:")
        print("    {}:\n {}".format(ema.average_name(w),sess.run(ema.average(w))))
        print("    {}:\n {}".format(ema.average_name(b),sess.run(ema.average(b))))
```

When I run it, weights & biases stay the same with each successive iterations!

I know there's something i'm missing (to update the parameters!) but unable to identify! The doc isn't much helpful either. Thanks a lot for any clue any guidance on how I can proceed further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is missing is actually calling the training step. Ema variable are being updated, but don't change, because weights don't. There are 2 possible solutions.

1. Explicitly add training step to `sess.run`:

   `_ = sess.run([opt, training_op], feed_dict=feed_train)`
2. Add dependency - now tensorflow will know that everytime you call ema update it needs to perform training step before computing it.

   `ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.50,name='EMA')
   with tf.control_dependencies([opt]):
       training_op = ema.apply([w, b])`